# How to efficiently store the text content in Elasticsearch and make it searchable

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have the data in the file in this form, how to split the different section and store it in Elasticsearch index and search based on some unique number.

**Sample data:**

```
SSLEGGU00402-IM    13949 13949    58     1  285228   3094844 1U00402-IM    13949
   200  1490   400  1490   600  1490   800  1490  1000  1490 2U00402-IM    13949
  1200  1490  1400  1491  1600  1493  1800  1497  2000  1504 3U00402-IM    13949
SSLEGGU00412-IM    13885 13885    58     1  286359   3094844 1U00412-IM    13885
   200  1489   400  1489   600  1489   800  1489  1000  1489 2U00412-IM    13885
  1200  1489  1400  1490  1600  1493  1800  1497  2000  1505 3U00412-IM    13885
```

I would like to store `SSLEGGU00402` as a separate document and `SSLEGGU00412` as a separate document and i need to search based on the same.

Does Elasticsearch by-default gives some way to split this text and store it or we need to split it programmatically and store as Elasticsearch Index.

Comment: Can you show a sample JSON of how you'd expect those documents to look like?

Comment: @Val: I would like to store first three lines as one document and so on.. this is to start with .. may be later point of time.. we might need to store each entry as separate field.

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to look into [[image]elasticsearch](/questions/tagged/elasticsearch)'s `Ingest Node` and its `Processors`. They can be used to apply transformations on documents before they get indexed.

> If your source data is well-defined and adheres to a specific pattern, I hope you can make use of `GROK` processor to convert it to a structured JSON for indexing.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/grok-processor.html

In case if you have sophisticated logic that needs to be applied for data pre-processing, you can make your own pipeline

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/ingest.html

Thanks.